# No Module named arcade

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, arcade

For class I am using python arcade. I installed it with `pip install arcade`. When I attempt to import it with `import arcade` it pops up `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcade'`.

Ive uninstalled and reinstalled arcade. It shows up when I enter `pip freeze`. I am using VS Code on windows 10.
When I look in the 'errors' tab in VS Code it says "Unable to import 'arcade' pylint(import-error)[3,1]"

Comment: Run `pip install pylint` and then try again and troubleshoot pylint in visual studio.

Comment: How does your directory tree structure look like ? Do you have sub directories ?

Comment: sounds like you possibly have 2 different python installations (eg. system and anaconda).  try to find out where your python install is (don't know the Win cmd, but on Mac/*nix you'd do: `which python` and `which pip` - if they are different directories, then `pip` will install to a different python install)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem. 
The solution in my case was installing modules by running
`python -m pip install <module>` instead of `pip install <module>`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in the jupyter notebook and I have solved it as follow:

```
pip install notebook
```